# python: changing type of object so it dos not effects all the objects that have received it in the past

Tags: python, variables, types

So Ι have this python example:

```
In [1]: a=['1']

In [2]: b=a

In [3]: a[0] = int(a[0]) 

In [4]: type(a[0])
Out[4]: int

In [5]: type(b[0])
Out[5]: int
```

Why is `b[0]` an `int` and not a `str`?

How can Ι fix the problem?

Comment: Why should it be a str? You set it to an int.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're asking the same question as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list-in-python) but in a slightly less general way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because when you say `b=a`, python doesn't create a new list for `b`, with a copy of the elements in `a`. Rather, `b` is just another name for `a`, and points to the same location in memory. Whatever memory address holds the stuff that we call `a` is the same memory address that holds the stuff we call `b`. Since only one entity may occupy a given memory address at a given time, `a` and `b` are effectively synonyms - like giving your friend a nickname.

This can be verified with `id(...)`:

```
In [46]: a=['1']

In [47]: b=a

In [48]: id(a)==id(b)
Out[48]: True
```

Since lists are mutable, when you change the value of some index of a list, a new list is not created. Rather, the entity at the corresponding memory address of that list is replaced with a different entity.

So, back to that analogy about `b=a` being like giving your friend a nickname: If your friend's name is John, and your nickname for him is "J" (how unimaginative! I clearly need some coffee). Then if John dyes his hair blue, well then so has J. J doesn't manage to retain his hair color despite John having done so.

Similarly, `b` doesn't get to keep the `'1'`, despite `a` having changed.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem, it's how Python works.
When you create a variable in Python you are creating a `variable name` which is a `reference` to an object.

So what is happening here is that you are creating a `list` object containing the string `'1'`, and referencing this object with name `a`.
This line `b = a` will create a new `name` `b` which is also referencing the object `['1']`. Since `list` is a `mutable` object `a[0] = int(a[0])`, will change `in place` the `type` of (`string`) `'1'` to (`int`) `1`.
So because `a` and `b` are referencing the same object both will be type of `int`.